# Filebeat Nginx to capture vhost

Tags: kibana, filebeat

I'm using the ELK stack with Filebeat to capture Nginx logs, no special setup or anything. But I have multiple domains in multiple virtual hosts and from the logs in Kibana can't tell which line is a request for which vhost, there is simply no variable for that.

So how can I change the configuration to do that? Anyone please?

Comment: How does your nginx log entries look like ? And what do you expect to see in Kibana ? Please provide details and I may suggest something

Comment: A log line looks like this:
x.x.x.x - - [13/Nov/2018:08:00:37 +0100] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 302 37 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 ..."
Will simply adding an field for the vhost variable suffice? I probably need to configure it somewhere...

Comment: Yes, does $host variable work for you ? http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#var_host

Comment: So I've got $host in the log line now, but it doesn't make an appearance in Kibana. Probably more configuration needed.

Comment: How does your log file look now ? If filebeat is reading your updated logs and sending it to ES then those should appear in Kibana unless there are errors in filebeat logs

Comment: It looks like this: x.x.x.x - - [13/Nov/2018:08:00:37 +0100] "www.mydomain.de" "GET / HTTP/1.1" 302 37 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 ..."

Comment: Then it should also show in your Kibana if filebeat is reading and sending these logs to ES